# Why do questions or answers posted by new users not show up immediately for review?

Tags: discussion, review, new-users

I checked a lot of time that if a new user posted a question or answered a question, it won't immediately reflect in the review section; rather, it is available for review after ~5 minutes (I don't know the exact time). Why does it take this much time?

### Screenshots

Question asked 5 mins ago:

[image: Screenshot of question with timestamp "asked 5 mins ago"]

Review section when that question was less than 5 mins old:

[image: Screenshot showing empty review queues]

Review section when that questions after 5 mins:

[image: Screenshot showing one post in the "First Posts" review queue]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 6):

Questions aren't *constantly* scanned to be added to queues. Sometimes the scanner will get a question after it's been up for a few moments, other times it can take ten minutes.